# Jquery - Reference by ID - Supposed to return an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I just started using jQuery, and various sources suggest that the following should be used to reference an element by ID:

```
$("#imgThumbnail")
```

theoretically making something like this possible:

```
$("#imgThumbnail").src;
```

But my testing indicates that something like `$("#imgThumbnail")` returns an array, making the following necessary:

```
$("#imgThumbnail")[0].src;
```

Do I really need to reference by the index of the array every time I am trying to reference something by ID (i.e., `var oObj = $("#someobjectid")[0];` )?

Comment: yeah I randomly started having this same problem too and I don't believe any of the answers below solve it.

Answer (score 6):

You should get the src attribute to get the value

```
$("#imgThumbnail").attr('src');
```

Answer (score 6):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159587/jquery-subtleties/1159735#1159735) explains what the $ function returns and various ways to use it.

---

```
$(selector)
```

Returns a jQuery object, which could contain a number of DOM elements.

---

```
$(selector)[0] or $(selector).get(0)
```

Returns the first result as an actual DOM element.

---

```
$(selector).eq(0) or $($(selector).get(0))
```

Returns the DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object so that we can do stuff like:

```
$(selector).eq(0).addClass("deleted").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 3):

$(specifier) will return a collection, so yes if you want to call something on an individual member you need to pick which one.  In most cases though there is a collection operator you can use to achieve the same result.  For instance, you could call $('#imgThumbnail').attr('src', 'value')

Answer (score 1):

You should bear in mind that it's not really an array, it's a jQuery object which, among other things, allows array-style access

Answer (score 1):

```
$(whatever)
```

returns the jQuery object. On the jQuery object you can do jQuery and jQuery plugin things, eg. `.text()` to return the text inside the element or `.css("background", "pink")` to make the element(s) pink.

Since src isn't a jQuery thing you cannot access it. src is however both a HTML attribute, and you can access those with the attr method:

```
.attr("src")` and `.attr("src", "http://www.example.com/myimage.png")
```

src is also a DOM-property and you can access DOM-properties using `[index]` or by iterating through the jQuery object with each:

```
.each(function(){
  this.src = "http://www.example.com/myimage.png";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using .src with jQuery.

```
Try $("#imgThumbnail").attr('src');
```

(this will read the src attribute, you set it with a second arg if you like)

See here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr

Answer (score 0):

to set the src attribute use

```
$("#imgThumbnail").attr("src", value)
```

if you use something like a class selector or tag like so

```
$("img").attr("src", value)
```

It will modify all the image src attributes on the page. Hence the $ function returns an array.

And you do not need to reference it specifically.